# How to join 2 sql rows from one table into one in another

Tags: sql

I have a complex query and need to fetch from one table 2 records like this :

```
code | family | level
111     S1      niv 1
111     2       niv 2
```

and i need that in another query to come out as :

```
code | family1 | level1 | family2 | level2
111      S1       niv 1     2        niv 2
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Clue: Cross tab query

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  No one can help you if no one can understand you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this case is that you need to know in advance how many records you get for a given "code" and this number needs to be constant, otherwise you'd end up with result entries having a variable number of columns, which is unacceptable.

If, however, you know that you'll always have at most two records per code and DB engine supports CTE expressions, you can write something like this :

```
WITH codelist (code,level1,level2) AS 
(
    SELECT code,min(level),max(level)
      FROM yourtable 
  GROUP BY code
)

         SELECT a.code,
                b.family,a.level1,
                c.family,a.level2

           FROM codelist a

LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable b ON b.code = a.code
            AND b.level = a.level1

LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable c ON c.code = a.code
            AND c.level = a.level2

       ORDER BY a.code ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usin min and max aggregation functions are enough :

```
select max(code) code, 
       max(family) family1, min(level) level1,
       min(family) family2, max(level) level2
  from mytable;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5ab48/2)

Comment: Your solution is relevant but slightly flawed: you need a `GROUP BY` clause to enable aggregation functions, and `max(family)` will always return the highest name regardless of the rest, not the family name that matches the highest level.

Comment: Be careful, because it won't ALWAYS work and you'll not be able to notice it soon enough: you'll end up with MISMATCHING families and levels.

Comment: I'm sorry to insist about it but it's still not enough : you have swapped min(family) and max(family) but they remains independent from the other ones. Rename family "2" into "Z2" and they'll be mismatching again.

Comment: @Obsidian OP wants have just one row, and this SQL gives as shown in the demo.

Comment: Admit it remains wrong. If the query is valid only for specific values known in advance, then the query is useless. In any case, it doesn't answer the OP's question. It fetches a bunch of independent values that happen to fall on the correct combination when you tweak the query.

Comment: @Obsidian I do not need to admit anything, all roads go to Rome, and that was just a quick, practical answer for that special case. It doesn't mean wrong, but maybe not complete. If you wanna hear about your solution, it's OK, and your query gives right result +1, alright ?

Comment: I didn't want to be rude or something, sorry about this. It's not about my solution neither. Unfortunately, it's not a matter of completeness. There's a real mistake here in the sense that this query won't return the values you believe. And I needed to pinpoint that out because it's a common pitfall with aggregate functions, as well as one of the things that make the whole thing difficult. But thanks for taking time to help anyway.